# How to perform exception handling in struts1.3.8, raised from DAO layer?

Tags: exception, nullpointerexception, dao, struts-1

I'm using struts 1.3.8 and Spring Jdbc. How to handle the exceptions raised in the DAO layer and pass the infomation to the presentation layer. Should i have to handle in DAO layer or in Struts by using global forward can i do it??? which is best???
Thanks in Advance,
Laxman Chowdary

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/1.x/userGuide/building_controller.html#exception_handler

Comment: Hi Nizet, I already tried with that and not handled DAO exceptions.In that case the application is not working well.So should i have to handle the exceptions in DAO only ??? any other possibilities there with struts ????

Comment: An exception is an exception. If your action calls a DAO method and this DAO method throws an exception, the handler will be invoked, because Struts doesn't care whether the exception comes from a DAO or from your action code directly. If it's not working, show us the code of your action, the stack trace of the exception, and the configuration of the handler.

Comment: one more doubt, Which is good either handling exceptions in DAO layer or in struts using global forwards???? and in DAO layer we don't know what type of exception will be raised? so how to handle them in Struts??? means should we use specific Exception type or generic type?

Comment: What useful thing could you do if, in your DAO, a NullPointerException occurs? At least, in the presentation layer, you can display a "Some unexpected error occurred, please go back to the home page" page. That's what an exception handler is used for.